# Авторизация в ВК

Tags: curl, php, вконтакте

Почему не работает?

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['auth_email'];
$pass = $_POST['auth_password'];

$otvet=connect("http://login.vk.com/?act=login&email=".$email."&pass=".$pass);
If(!preg_match("/hash=([a-z0-9]{1,32})/",$otvet,$hash)){
die("Login incorrect");
}
$otvet=connect("http://vk.com/login.php?act=slogin&hash=".$hash[1]);
preg_match("/remixsid=(.*?);/",$otvet,$sid);
$cookie = "remixchk=5; remixsid=".$sid[1];

function connect($link,$cookie=null,$post=null){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
if($cookie !== null)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
if($post !== null)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
}
$otvet = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $otvet;
}
?>
```

Не входит в вк? (Точнее не приходит ни какого ответа)

Comment: Контакт просто принимать данные не будет, изучайте его формы ввода.

Comment: Есть масса причин, по которым вам не приходит ответ.

- не тот урл
- забыли какой-то параметр указать
- не указан юзерагент
- ...

Comment: Может, ещё и капчу просит.

Answer (score 4):

`login.vk.com` живет на `https`. Да и вообще, почему бы не сотворить `desktop`-приложение, получить для `vk.api` вечный `access_token` и делать запросы почти на все?

Comment: А через то что вы говорите можно подключатся к приложению и получать данные id и auth

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile читаете внимательно, строчку за строчкой. 

Создаете desktop-приложение, берете его id, лепите в ссылку для запроса авторизации приложения. Если все верно -- запрос вернет Вам access_token в hash части урла. Его использовать при каждом запросе, что ожидает его присутствие.

Потом выбираете метод отсюда: https://vk.com/dev/methods и читаете, какие параметры нужны. 

Стукать запрос (например, для "users.get") вот так: http://api.vk.com/method/users.get?uids=1

Ответ в json, парсить в ассоциативный массив так $data = json_decode("{...}");

Что не понятно - спросите